# SharePoint 2016 - How do you bulk add users to a new user group without AD or PowerShell that are already has users in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, excel, active-directory, user-accounts

We have SharePoint Enterprise 2016 at my work.  All users from all departments and units are already in the Global AD which is connected to SharePoint.  I want to create a user group in bulk from a file (Excel, CSV, etc.) that contains a certain list of users in my department.  These users are already in the list of all users from my work.  I can't use PowerShell.  If you have any suggestions, I'd very much appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just copy display names or email addresses of multiple users to the people picker field when adding users into one group in SharePoint 2016.

It will resolve the users if the display names or email addresses are right.
The format of multiple users like below, use semicolons to separate the multiple users.

Use email address: test1@contoso2016.com; test2@contoso2016.com;

Use display name: test1 zhang; test2 fan;

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for pointing out the semi-colons rather than commas.

Comment: If the reply is helpful to you, you could mark the reply as an answer. Thank you for your understanding.